# How to skip a directory in directory hierarchy?

Tags: bash

I have these kind of directory structure where I want to get a.txt

1. `folder1/f2/var/log/a.txt`
2. `folder1/var/log/a.txt`

I am taking the address of folder1 as an input in bash as `$logfile`.
So `$logfile` include folder1

Now if I want to access a.txt, I use this

`$logfile/var/log/a.txt`.

It works for the `folder1/var/log/a.txt`

How to make it work for `folder1/f2/var/log/a.txt`?

Any trick where it directly skips the in-between directory?

Comment: Please post your code. One line of code explains better that 15 words. I suggest you also to avoid vague descriptions as "it doesn't work".

Comment: You can do `$logfile/{*/,}log/a.txt`.

Comment: `$logfile/var/log/a.txt.

It works for the folder1/var/log/a.txt

How to make it work for folder1/f2/var/log/a.txt?` Just `$logfile/f2/var/log/a.txt`?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes that can be done but I'm hardcoding `$logfile/var/log/a.txt` in a bash script.